# Inserting numeric data into table

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can you please help me?

Application: E-commerce website (classic ASP/Vbs)

Local PC: MSSQL 2005 DB with windows 7

2 tables: (dbo.products and dbo.basket)

Both tables have a column named "prize" with the same data type: "numeric (18, 2)" 
My problem is the following: I am inserting with a submit form (with the INSERT INTO method) the value from the table dbo.products (column "prize") to the table dbo.basket (column "prize"). The value is "200,33". In my local database everything works absolutely perfect and the value is written correctly to the dbo.basket table as "200,33"

BUT

When I am doing the same thing to my hosting server (also MSSQL 2005 like mine), the value is not transferred correctly from one table to the other. Is multiplied X 100. For example the value 200,33 from the dbo.products, has been converted to 20.033,00 to the dbo.basket !!!!!!

Can someone please help me? What I am doing wrong? Why is this difference between my local MSSQL 2005 and my hosting MSSQL 2005?

Any help will be truly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked in your database that and cast() is applied on that column while sending data,
if so it will come, then remove the cast(), it will be cleared.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Can you declare please what is the "cast()" exactly is. My English in not so good..

Comment: Cast() and Format() are the functions used in so many scenarios. in this case cast(20033 as decimal(8,2))  will be displayed as 20033.00 and Format(20033,2) will be displayed as 20,033.00

Comment: Dear Guru,
I have tried "CDbl" with all available formats but with no success. Any other idea?